# putty double click on session name does not automatically start session

Tags: putty

all the docs on putty say, "To start a saved session immediately: double-click on the session name in the list box."  This works on all of my saved sessions except for the session I most recently created.  Putty does not automatically start that session on double-click. I found no settings in putty that control this.  I recall this happening on other installs of putty but never found a solution for it.  Has anyone else experienced this? What is different about this session?

Comment: Are you sure you have a Host Name (or IP address) specified in the profile?  It won't start without one.

Comment: what do you mean by the profile?  I have a session saved and it is listed in saved sessions box and it has a name in addition to some other settings (like username) and the username setting is respected when I paste the session name into the Host Name (or IP address) box

Comment: Sorry, I meant session.  You need to save a Host Name (or IP address) as part of the session in order for it to open by double click.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in case double-click on a saved session does not work:

2. Delete the saved session by clicking on the 'Delete' button in PuTTY configuration
3. Re-enter the hostname/IP address in both 'Host Name (or IP address)' field and 'Saved Session' field.
4. Save the session by clicking 'Save' Button
5. Double-click on the newly saved session